# Как использовать несколько COUNT в одном запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle

Предположим, есть таблица:

```
Table:
--------------------
  name  |  food
--------------------
  Вася  |  апельсин
  Вася  |  апельсин
  Вася  |  банан
  Миша  |  апельсин
  Миша  |  ананас
  Миша  |  ананас
  Катя  |  апельсин
  Катя  |  ананас
```

Я хочу привести её к виду

```
-----------------------------
  name  |  count1  |  count2
-----------------------------
  Вася  |    2     |    1
  Миша  |    1     |    2
  Катя  |    1     |    1
```

Где в count1 считаем только апельсины, а в count2 - ананасы ИЛИ бананы.

То есть если бы считали только count1, то мы бы сделали

```
select name, count(food)
from table
where food = 'апельсин'
group by name, food
```

А как вытащить два таких счетчика одним запросом?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так:

```
select name,
  sum(case when food = 'апельсин' then 1 else 0 end) as oranges,
  sum(case when food in ('ананас', 'банан') then 1 else 0 end) as pineapples_and_bananas
from table
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще с пивотом (если у вас oracle 11 или старше) и `decode` для объединения значений:

```
with t (name, food) as (
      select 'Вася', 'апельсин' from dual union all
      select 'Вася', 'апельсин' from dual union all
      select 'Вася', 'банан' from dual union all
      select 'Миша', 'апельсин' from dual union all
      select 'Миша', 'ананас' from dual union all
      select 'Миша', 'ананас' from dual union all
      select 'Катя', 'апельсин' from dual union all
      select 'Катя', 'ананас' from dual)
select *
  from (select name, decode(food, 'ананас', 'ананас или банан', 'банан', 'ананас или банан', food) food2
          from t)
 pivot(count(*) for food2 in ('апельсин' "orange", 'ананас или банан' "ananas or banan"));

NAME         orange ananas or banan
-------- ---------- ---------------
Вася              2               1 
Катя              1               1 
Миша              1               2
```

Если у вас всего два-три столбца с разными "каунтами", то проще делать через `case`, как Yura Ivanov предложил, а если большой набор разных значений, и надо делать много запросов с разными агрегатными функциями, то лучше пивот.

**UPD**
Можно еще не делать `decode` вообще, а просто просуммировать столбцы. Так даже намного проще будет:

```
select name, "orange", "ananas" + "banan"
  from t
pivot(count(*) for food in ('апельсин' "orange", 'ананас' "ananas", 'банан' "banan"));
```

Comment: Здесь можно также заменить decode на case.

Comment: @0xdb decode обычно короче писать :) Хотя `case` универсальнее.

Comment: "универсальнее" лучше сказать - стандартнее. И потери в быстродествии, которые были замечены в какойто старой версии, уже (вроде) не существуют.  "короче писать"  - ну мы же не пишем ручками, а копи-паста или IDE дополняет.

Comment: @0xdb Тут вообще без них можно обойтись. Я в ответ добавил второй вариант.

Comment: А, понял, но больше 1-го + не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас будет условие where food = 'апельсин', как в примере, то одно из значений, в котором считаются не апельсины всегда будет равно 0.

Одним запросом можно сделать с применением вложенных запросов.

```
select name, 
(select count(foot) from table b where a.name = b.name and foot = 'апельсин') orange,
(select count(foot) from table b where a.name = b.name and foot = 'банан') banana
from table a
group by name
```